# LWJGL 3 as a method of drawing charts

Tags: java, swing, opengl, canvas, lwjgl

A friend asked me to develop a chart setup for a machine he is building. He has some very specific requirements about how the charts need to be displayed, and no existing api will satisfy those requirements.
So I need to make a custom chart renderer, one option was to just take any java 2D canvas or to use OpenGL, which would be LWJGL.
I used LWJGL 2 in the past, and i know it can be a canvas element, while LWJGL 3 can't. So the only solution I can have here is either have it broken up in frames like Gimp is, or have the gui as part of the LWJGL 3 frame. Those solutions are not appreciated for what needs to be done.
Is there a way I could wrap the LWJGL 3 frame as a internal frame, or anything to make it stick to a java swing or java fx gui?

I use Java because I know it best, I don't have so much experiences in other languages.

Comment: I don't believe there are no charting options out there for your needs, making your own will be an absolute nightmare and is bound to fail. I don't think anyone has ever made their own with no help successfuly, it has always involved the help of others. Eg matplotlib, jfreechar.

Comment: Thig is I need to be able to have selectors like in audio editing programs, so that I can apply some functions (like derivation and integration) to the selected area.
I did not notice such options in any of the existing ones, but I might overlooked the feature.

Comment: You mean like draging 2 sliders to select an interval? I am going to make an example of this with jfreechart, you are going to upvote it once it is ready in 30 mins lolz.

Comment: Yes sliders, but what I fear is that the friend of mine might have other crazy ideas, so if you can please say how do I add custom functionality to jfreechart.

Edit: I already did some work with jfreechart, and the thing that was bothering is that I could not figure out how to add zoom and motion buttons that would be controlled by the gui itself. Something that does not require poking with the mouse pointer on the chart itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here is an interval chart:

[image]

I cant fit all the code on here unforunately, I will post it on github. But anything you can imagine can be done, I am not going to go through every way jfreechart can be customized but with some digging you can find the answers.

You can find the code on https://github.com/derrick3192/sliderchartdemo.git

If you want to add zoom buttons and what not I suggest you look at the:

plot.getDomainAxis().setRange

Or

plot.getRangeAxis().setRange

But I don't mean this offensivily but you can't come on stackoverflow with low rep (even though I don't have much rep) and claim all the charting libraries are not good enough, and you have to make your own, you will get downvoted for that so tread lightly.

Comment: Thanks for the code!
I will talk to that friend of mine and see if he is satisfied with that.
I hope he will, and I hope he does not come up with something unheard of (not strange of him). Also he or me might need something completely different to be used with LWJGL 3 which would also require a gui, but seems I'll just have to wait for the implementation of the canvas mode.

I never claimed that such functionality did not exist in any charts, I just stated that I don't know about such features, and also I never saw any program except audio editors have such functionality.

Comment: And as for my low rep, I am a student at the moment, and I don't know  all of the tricks of the trade yet, so please don't get offended on my question which may seem misleading.

With the original question still being unsolved, I'll call it solved here since you helped with my initial problem, and I will say you can't stitch the frames, since all day of googling did not help.

Answer (score -2):

Another solution is to use JOGL instead of LWJGL3 since it can be used as a canvas. Works in a similar way, and the same thing can be achieved with it.